# javascript "push" not recognised, not sure why

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript.

I am trying to add an entry to an existing object, as a part of an exercise to develop a Chromecast Sender app on a Raspberry Pi 3. It will be based on the g00gle samples which have a variable's structure as shown below.

The first thing I need to do is be confident in manipulating objects, adding, modifying and removing items.

In the example below the "push" line throws an error and I don't know why. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Uncaught TypeError: movies3.push is not a function at broken.html:28

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var movies3 = 
{ 'categories' : 
    [{ 'name' : 'Movies', 
                'videos' : [ { 'description' : "TEST 1",
                                   'sources' : ['http://TEST1.SOURCES.mp4'],
                                  'subtitle' : 'TEST1 SUBTITLE',
                                     'thumb' : 'TEST1 THUMB',
                                     'title' : 'TEST1 TITLE'
                             },
                             { 'description' : 'a2', 'sources' : ['a2.mp4'], 'subtitle' : 'a2 subtitle', 'thumb' : 'a2 thumb', 'title' : 'a2 title' }
                           ]
     }
    ]
};    
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
movies3.push ( { categories: [ { name: 'Movies', videos: [ { description : "d1 description", sources : ['http://...d1...mp4'], subtitle : 'd1 subtitle', thumb : 'd1 thumb', title : 'd1 title' } ] } ] } );
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
console.log(movies3);
document.write('<style>');
document.write('h1{text-align:left;}');
document.write('h4{text-align:left;margin:0;padding:0px;background:#f4f4f4;}');
document.write('li{text-align:left;margin:50;padding:0px}');
document.write('</style>');
document.write('<div id="container">');
document.write('<h1> My Favourite movies3</h1>');
for (var i = 0; i < movies3['categories'][0]['videos'].length; i++) {
   document.write('<h4>' + movies3['categories'][0]['videos'][i].title + '</h4>');
   document.write('<ul>');
   document.write('<li> subtitle    ' + movies3['categories'][0]['videos'][i].subtitle + '</li>');
   document.write('<li> description ' + movies3['categories'][0]['videos'][i].description + '</li>');
   document.write('<li> thumb       ' + movies3['categories'][0]['videos'][i].thumb + '</li>');
   for (var j = 0; j < movies3['categories'][0]['videos'][i].sources.length; j++) {
      document.write('<ul>');
      document.write('<li> sources ' + j + ' ' + movies3['categories'][0]['videos'][i].sources[j] + '</li>');
      document.write('</ul>');
   };
   document.write('</ul>');
};
document.write('</div>');
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: `push()` is a function that is only available for arrays. `movies3` is an object.

Comment: `movies3` is an object (it was made with curly braces) and not an array (square-brackets).

Comment: movies3.push() gives you Uncaught TypeError: movies3.push is not a function. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have defined **`movies`** as a object. where **`categories`** is an **`array`**. You cannot use .push over an object, it is available only with arrays.

You need

```js
var movies3 = 
{ 'categories' : 
    [{ 'name' : 'Movies', 
                'videos' : [ { 'description' : "TEST 1",
                                   'sources' : ['http://TEST1.SOURCES.mp4'],
                                  'subtitle' : 'TEST1 SUBTITLE',
                                     'thumb' : 'TEST1 THUMB',
                                     'title' : 'TEST1 TITLE'
                             },
                             { 'description' : 'a2', 'sources' : ['a2.mp4'], 'subtitle' : 'a2 subtitle', 'thumb' : 'a2 thumb', 'title' : 'a2 title' }
                           ]
     }
    ]
};    
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
movies3.categories.push ({
  "name": "Movies",
  "videos": [
    {
      "description": "d1 description",
      "sources": [
        "http:p4"
      ],
      "subtitle": "d1 subtitle",
      "thumb": "d1 thumb",
      "title": "d1 title"
    }
  ]
});

console.log(movies3);
```

Comment: ok thank you for your clarification and answer, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with an object, arrays have access to the .push prototype. Adding new items to objects should be as follows

`movies3.categories.push({ ... })`